# Why Xcode does not display app storyboard?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, storyboard

I have an issue with a storyboard in Xcode 12.4
My storyboard is not displayed correctly

[image: storyboard]

I tried these steps:

- restart Xcode
- restart macOS
- clean Deriver data
- cmnd + shift + k
- change device

Error Log:

```
Encountered an error communicating with IBAgent-iOS. (Failure reason: IBAgent-iOS (-1) failed to launch): Failed to launch IBAgent-iOS via CoreSimulator spawn (Failure reason: Failed to spawn IBAgent-iOS on iPhone 12 Pro Max (FF7523FB-FD48-40DF-9429-0C24F7EF6A64, iOS 14.4, Booted)): Invalid device state

Error Domain=com.apple.InterfaceBuilder Code=-1 "Encountered an error communicating with IBAgent-iOS." UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=IBAgent-iOS (-1) failed to launch, NSUnderlyingError=0x7fe409786840 {Error Domain=com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimError Code=405 "Failed to launch IBAgent-iOS via CoreSimulator spawn" UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=Failed to spawn IBAgent-iOS on iPhone 12 Pro Max (FF7523FB-FD48-40DF-9429-0C24F7EF6A64, iOS 14.4, Booted), NSLocalizedDescription=Failed to launch IBAgent-iOS via CoreSimulator spawn, NSUnderlyingError=0x7fe3dc535660 {Error Domain=com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimError Code=405 "Invalid device state" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Invalid device state}}}}, NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Please check Console.app for crash reports for "IBAgent-iOS" for further information., NSLocalizedDescription=Encountered an error communicating with IBAgent-iOS.}
```

Thank you for your answers :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although the other answer might work, too, there is actually a much easier and less time-consuming way to solve this. All you need to do is the following:

1. Press <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>⇧</kbd><kbd>K</kbd> to run **Clean Build Folder**.
2. Quit Xcode.
3. Open Activity Monitor.
4. Force quit all processes called `IBAgent-iOS`.
5. Open Xcode.

Now it should work again.